# How to resolve Kaldi ASR feature extraction error?

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, kaldi

I am working on the Kaldi tutorial for dummies. I followed every step. Now at the end when I run the main script name run.sh I get these errors. I have been trying to resolve this for hours now. I have setup also manually setup path in path.sh.

The problem is here in the decode.sh script. It exits from line 83, instead of going down. I am attaching the decode.sh file for reference. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

here is the screenshot of terminal. For both Mono decoding and TRI1 decoding it say that

```
steps/decode.sh: Error: no such file data/test/split1/1/feats.scp
```

[image: Mono Decoding]
[TRI1 Decoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLucE.png)

[Decode.sh](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/master/egs/wsj/s5/steps/decode.sh)

Answer (score 2):

The message tells you miss the extracted features for test. You need to repeat feature extraction step for test and watch the errors in the process:

```
steps/make_mfcc.sh --nj $nj --cmd "$train_cmd" data/test exp/make_mfcc/test $mfccdir
```